# How to join more than one row if the primary key is the same (so the output is just one row)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorry if the title is a little bit confusing.

First, this is my code.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT t.idBerita, t.judul, t.headline, t.waktuAsal, t.lokasi, t.isiBerita, t.penulis, t.editor, t.sumber, t.waktuPengambilan, k.idKategori, g.namaKategori
    FROM tabelberita t
    LEFT JOIN tabelketerangan k ON t.idBerita = k.idBerita
    LEFT JOIN tabelkategori g ON k.idKategori = g.idKategori
    ORDER BY waktuPengambilan DESC";

$getnews = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getnews)){
    $id = $row['idBerita'];
    $judul = $row['judul'];
    $headline = $row['headline'];
    $waktuAsal = $row['waktuAsal'];
    $lokasi = $row['lokasi'];
    $isiBerita = $row['isiBerita'];
    $penulis = $row['penulis'];
    $editor = $row['editor'];
    $sumber = $row['sumber'];
    $waktuPengambilan = $row['waktuPengambilan'];
    $kategori = $row['namaKategori'];
    
    echo '<h3 style="text-align:center; font-size:20px">' .$judul. '<br></h3>';
    echo '<p style="text-align:center"><i>' .$headline. ' - <b>' .$sumber. '</b></i></p><br>';
    echo '<p style="font-size:11px">Oleh: ' .$penulis. '<br>';
    echo 'Editor : ' .$editor. '<br>';
    echo 'Kategori : ' .$kategori. '<br>';
    echo 'Waktu Pengambilan : ' .$waktuPengambilan. '</p><br>';
    echo '<div id="isi' .$id. '" style="display:none;">';
    echo '<p style="text-align:justify">&emsp;' .$isiBerita. '</p></div><br>';
    echo '<a href="javascript:showMore('.$id.')" id="more' .$id. '" style="display:block;"> Read More >></a>';
    echo '<a href="javascript:showLess('.$id.')" id="less' .$id. '" style="display:none;"> Read Less >></a>';
    echo '<br><br><br><br>';
    echo '';            
}
?>
```

The table "tabelketerangan" has column idBerita, idKategori, and namaKategori. idBerita and idKategori is the primary key. idBerita is FK from tabelberita.

the relationship is one to many for tabelberita and tabelketerangan. that means one tabelberita could have many tabelketerangan but one tabelketerangan could only have one tabelberita.

i have an entry, which is the tabelberita have two tabelketerangan.

if i echo the query, it would give me something like this..

> =======================
>
> idBerita    kategori
>
> ======================
>
> id1        kat1
>
> id1        kat2
>
> ======================

how to make it show like this??

> ==================================
>
> idBerita    kategori1    kategori2
>
> ==================================
>
> id1        kat1         kat2
>
> ==================================

thanks in advance. :)

Comment: can u make sqlfiddle?

Comment: what's a sqlfiddle??

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I have one clarification! Your query executing correctly. but u need o/p like in column, not in row while fetching?? correct??

Comment: i need output that join the idBerita column as in above explanation. on the 2nd table it didn't join the idBerita column and shows duplicate idBerita instead.

Comment: i mean on the tables that i posted in my question.